# SSH and maxstartups confusion

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, openssh, sshd

In the sshd_condifg I have set following entries:

```
maxstartups 50:100:50
clientalivecountmax 3
maxauthtries 3
```

But still in the `ps` results I can see at least processes that look like this:

```
ps -fe|grep aaa_test
(...)
root     11014  5023  0 Oct13 ?        00:00:00 sshd: aaa_test [priv]
root     11164 11014  0 Oct13 ?        00:00:00 sshd: aaa_test@notty
(...)
ps -fe|grep notty|wc -l
245
```

Why is this happening? How can I limit the user to open max 3 connections using same `username` and maximum of 50 connections in total (all users)?

Answer (score 0):

According to manual, you can use simply `maxstartups 50`, which will be equivalent for your line and much more readable.

But reading further, you see that this limit is only for

> MaxStartups
>
> Specifies the maximum number of concurrent **unauthenticated connections** to the SSH daemon. [...]

Option `ClientAliveCountMax` is used for totally different thing than you think. Have a look into manual page:

> ClientAliveCountMax
>
> Sets the number of **client alive messages** (see below) which may be sent without sshd(8) receiving any messages back from the client. [...]

It doesn't specify anything about concurrency.

If I am right, there is no way to limit authenticated users on the `ssh` level. But you can do so on the level of application using some global `.profile` bash script or `ForcedCommand` option in ssh, which will count existing connection on system and based on the result, allow or deny to continue.